# Why does estimatesmartfee not return < 5 sats/vB even for long confirmation times?

Tags: fee-estimation

We find that `estimatesmartfee` will not return results lower than 5 sats/vB, even though many transactions are completing at much lower fee rates.

Looking at [the implementation of `estimatesmartfee`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/rpc/fees.cpp#L88), it bounds the result to the higher of three values:

```
CFeeRate feeRate{fee_estimator.estimateSmartFee(conf_target, &feeCalc, conservative)};
if (feeRate != CFeeRate(0)) {
    CFeeRate min_mempool_feerate{mempool.GetMinFee()};
    CFeeRate min_relay_feerate{mempool.m_min_relay_feerate};
    feeRate = std::max({feeRate, min_mempool_feerate, min_relay_feerate});
    result.pushKV("feerate", ValueFromAmount(feeRate.GetFeePerK()));
} else {
    errors.push_back("Insufficient data or no feerate found");
    result.pushKV("errors", errors);
}
result.pushKV("blocks", feeCalc.returnedTarget);
```

Therefore we need to ensure `min_mempoool_feerate` and `min_relay_feerate` are both below 5000 sat/vKB on the nodes used for estimation.

- Looks like `min_relay_feerate` seems to come from `m_min_relay_feerate{opts.min_relay_feerate}` [in src/txmempool.cpp](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/txmempool.cpp#L409C1-L410C1) which comes from [`DEFAULT_MIN_RELAY_TX_FEE` defaulted to 1000](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/92704535f66976c09a658348e554d47b7f7bcf6e/src/policy/policy.h#L57)
- `min_mempool_feerate` coming from mempool.GetMinFee() seems to inherit a minimum from `incremental_relay_feerate{DEFAULT_INCREMENTAL_RELAY_FEE}` [where `DEFAULT_INCREMENTAL_RELAY_FEE` default is 1000](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/policy/policy.h#L35C61-L35C65)

Does anyone know what else holds it this high?

Answer (score 3):

Turned out we had an override for `minrelaytxfee` in the config file:

```
# Mempool
minrelaytxfee=0.00005
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for returning to answer your own question! Welcome to Bitcoin Stack Exchange.